# How to use substr with atof?

Tags: c++, string, double, root, atof

Reading from a `.txt` file, I would like to convert some values from a file, converting a `string` into `double`s. Normally, I can print the desired values:

```
string line;
ifstream f; 
f.open("set11.txt");

if(f.is_open()) {

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        
        getline(f, line);
        cout << "Voltage " << i  << ": " << line.substr(0, 9) << endl;
    }
}

f.close();
```

Terminal:

```
Voltage 0: 5.0000000
Voltage 1: 8.0000000
Voltage 2: 1.1000000
```

However, when I try to make them `double`, I replace the command with

```
cout << "Voltage " << i  << ": " << atof(line.substr(0, 9)) << endl;
```

and I get the following error:

```
    Voltage 0: Error: atof parameter mismatch param[0] C u C:\Users\User\Desktop\Physics\FTE\Root\set11.c(26)
(class G__CINT_ENDL)9129504
*** Interpreter error recovered ***
```

Any clues here? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I'm quite new to C++

Comment: `line.substr(0, 9).c_str()?` As is described in the documentation of [`std::atof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof), it accepts `const char*`, and `std::string` is not that.

Comment: [`std::stof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)? Includes better validation and allows better error handling.

Comment: "set11.c" is a pretty odd name for a C++ source file.

Comment: `std::stod` if doubles are wanted.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thanks alot!

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default initializing them and immediately overwriting the default value. In this case, that means changing `ifstream f; f.open("set11.txt");` to `ifstream f("set11.txt");`. Also, you don't need to call `f.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`atof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof) takes a `const char*` as parameter, while you are passing `std::string`

Use [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) instead:

```
   cout << "Voltage " << i  << ": " << stod(line.substr(0, 9)) << endl;
```

Or convert your `std::string` to a `const char*` using the `.c_str()` function and then pass that as parameter to `atof`:

```
   cout << "Voltage " << i  << ": " << stod(line.substr(0, 9).c_str()) << endl;
```

Comment: If `stod` could take a `string_view` this would be easy and great. Alas...